# Append one file to two files in unix script

Tags: files, scripting

I need to append one trail record to both the files.

```
cat file1 >> file2
```

this appends everything in `file1` to `file2`

My requirement is to append to `file1` content to both `file2` and `file3`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `tee`:

```
tee -a file2 file3 < file1
```

`tee` send its input to each of the files specified as arguments to it. Usually it overwrites, but `-a` is tells it to append.